# installing xdebug with php 5.6.3, no xdebug info next to zend logo

Tags: php, centos, xdebug

i have installed xdebug on centos,and run 'php -m' there r two xdebug between modules, but on phpinfo() page , i can not see any xdebug info , i have no idea.

php.ini

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
```

---

this is 'php -v' info:

```
Failed loading opcache.so:  opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so:  
/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so:  
undefined symbol: zend_execute_ex
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2014 19:56:14) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Is `/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so` the right path? Does it have the right permissions if it is?

Comment: @Anthony i think so ,[no-debug-non-zts-20131226]# ls
opcache.a  opcache.so  xdebug.so

Comment: Is it executable and set to the right owner/group?

Comment: [root@localhost no-debug-non-zts-20131226],  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 852357 May 10 22:26 xdebug.so